# Byte Array to Hexadecimal String Conversion

Tags: c#, unit-conversion

Another journey down the difficult path! I'd like to know if there's anything I haven't accounted for, if this can be significantly improved, etc.

(Just as a side-note, I know that some of the formatting is a bit off; some places are spaced out a bit to make it more visually appealing.)

```
using System;

namespace Data
{
    public class BinaryHelper
    {
        public static string ByteToHexString (byte[] bytes)
        {
            char[] c = new char[bytes.Length * 2];
            byte b;

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) {
                b = ((byte)(bytes [i] >> 4));
                c [i * 2] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30);
                b = ((byte)(bytes [i] & 0xF));
                c [i * 2 + 1] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30);
            }

            return new string (c);
        }

        public static byte[] HexStringToByte (string hex)
        {
            int len = hex.Length;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[len / 2];

            for (int i = 0; len > i; i += 2) {
                bytes [i / 2] = Convert.ToByte (hex.Substring (i, 2), 16);
            }

            return bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask yourself "how can I make the meaning and intention of the code more clear?"

Consider making small helper methods rather than duplicating code:

```
static byte HighNibble(byte b) => (byte)(b >> 4);
static byte LowNibble(byte b) => (byte)(b & 0xF);
static char NibbleToHex => ... etc.
```

And now instead of

```
    b = ((byte)(bytes [i] >> 4));
    c [i * 2] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30)
    b = ((byte)(bytes [i] & 0xF));
    c [i * 2 + 1] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30);
```

Which is *overwhelming* in the sheer amount of punctuation, we have:

```
 c [i * 2] = NibbleToHex(HighNibble(bytes[i])); 
 c [i * 2 + 1] = NibbleToHex(LowNibble(bytes[i]));
```

So much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

I found the magic numbers in this line less than obvious:

```
c [i * 2] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30);
```

`0x30` is clearly '0', however `0x37` is well... '7'.  I actually find this more expressive, even though it's longer:

```
c[i * 2] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 'A' - 10: b + '0');
```

If you're interested you can also find a rather more concise version of `ByteToArrayString` which makes use of `BitConverter` to perform the translation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/592182).  It essentially becomes a one-liner:

```
return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-","");
```